# Circuit still powered after switching off circuit breaker and light switch

Tags: electrical

I was changing some outdoor lights. I had the circuit breaker off (which stopped the lights from working) and the switch off. I used a contactless circuit tester and a testing screwdriver which suggested there was no current.

When working on the live wire I felt a slight buzz - not strong enough to call it a shock - so I shorted it to ground with a screwdriver and there was a spark.  After that there is no more buzz from the wire and nothing tripped.

Given the circuit breaker is off how was it possible to get a very small shock from the live wire? Is it residual charge in appliances on the circuit discharging?  Is there anything one should do when working in this situation?

Comment: How big of a spark?  Tiny blue?  Or OMG I can't see anymore white?

Comment: It was a very slight buzz, a tingle.  The spark was also very small.

Comment: Well, that's a load coming on, then... not a short to ground.  I would say that any advertised claims about the breaker being off are highly exaggerated.

Comment: Would it not continue to give a buzz if the board remained as it was? Once it was shorted it was totally benign and nothing tripped or changed on the board. That is what is so confusing!

Answer (score 3):

I would be looking at a multi wire branch circuit that was not handle tied OR possibly someplace the neutrals for 2 circuits got mixed up. Kind of the same thing but if the neutral was returning current from a different breaker you have turned off you could get a shocking experience, I have found both issues in the past and that is where I would be looking.

Comment: That's exactly how I found out about MWBC's  in my younger years.+

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Would it not continue to give a shock / spark? Or would the symptoms stop after it had been shorted?  That's why I don't think it is a neutral issue - but I very much could be wrong as I'm clearly no expert in this.

Comment: It would depend on the load on the other circuit if a mwbc , many years back handle tied were not required and I got zapped a few times at first I thought it was “static” or some kind of “phantom voltage” until tracing it back and found a mwbc with no handle tie. The next time I was sure it was a mwbc and it ended up being 3 circuits with neutrals mixed up in a switch setup. I have seen these issues many times since. As far as phantom voltages I have seen voltage but never enough current to have a flash as 120v is the max voltage to ground (in US). static shocks are usually thousands of volts.